# Text Box Does Not Seem to Appear (XlsxWriter)

Tags: python, textbox, xlsxwriter

I've followed the documentation on XlsxWriter but was not able to create a textbox. Perhaps I'm missing something. the following is my code:

```
    packlist_name2 = "Packlist2_%s.xlsx" %(Machine_Serial.iloc[0]['2'])
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(packlist_name2)
    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('TextBox') 

    text = 'PACKLIST\n \n Serial No: \n ............'
    options = {'width': 2000,
       'height': 2000,
       'x_offset': 10,
       'y_offset': 10,
       'fill':{'color':'white'},
       'border': {'color': '#800000', 'width': 6, 'dash_type': 'solid'},
       'align' : {'horizontal':'center', 'vertical': 'middle'},
        'font': {'name': 'Times New Roman', 'size':36}
       }
   worksheet.insert_textbox('B2', text, options)
```

Help much appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: 1. You have 4 spaces too much in each line of code in your post. 2. You do not save the worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

Found out my mistake; Had openpyxl functions placed after saving the above textbox.